# Que veut dire l’expression “secouer le cul” ?

Tags: expressions

l’expression “secouer le cul” veut dire quoi exactement? et est-elle très vulgaire?

je l’ai entendu par hasard dans un contexte qui était censé être “professionnel” et j’étais un peu sous le choc...

Answer (score 9):

L'expression ***se** secouer le cul*, sans être très vulgaire, est bien sûr très familière. Elle existe aussi sous les formes *se bouger le cul* et *se bouger les fesses*.

Elle peut signifier *danser* ou *twerker* mais dans le contexte de la question, elle veut dire *s'activer, sortir de sa léthargie, se mettre activement au travail, accélérer la cadence, etc.*

Il n'est pas très étonnant de l'entendre dans un contexte professionnel. Elle peut aussi faire partie du discours de motivation d'un entraineur à son équipe.

Comment: Sounds like a combination of English "shake your ass" and "move your ass". Interesting.

Comment: Donc ce n’est pas offensif de l’entendre par exemple d’un responsable ?

Comment: Tout dépend du contexte, du ton et de la forme. Il y a une différence entre *Eh, les gars, il va falloir un peu vous secouer le cul si vous voulez gagner cette prime !* et *Tu vas te secouer le cul tout de suite ou tu prends la porte !* mais dans les deux cas, c'est plus du parler très direct qu'une insulte.

Comment: @frenchlearner287228 "offensif" n'est pas une traduction directe de l'anglais "offensive", il faudrait plutôt dire "blessant" ou "offensant". Mais comme jilliagre l'a dit, le contexte va déterminer s'il fallait s'en choquer ou pas. A noter qu'il n'y a aucun connotation sexuelle à l'expression, si c'était ça votre inquiétude.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Between [*Shake Your Booty*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3fZuW-aJsg) ;-) and *Kick one's ass* [(*The professor's speech today kind of kicked my ass and made me realize I need to start applying myself.*)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Kick+Your+Ass)

Comment: [_Se grouiller_](https://youtu.be/HjxcWqwsdoY)... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> je l’ai entendu par hasard dans un contexte qui était censé être “professionnel” et j’étais un peu sous le choc...

Just to add to jlliagre's great answer, the connotation in a professional setting is that whoever uses the term "se secouer/bouger le cul" typically wants to convey some frustration on slowly some process/work is going and they want it to go faster. The translation "Move your ass" (= be more active) is a good translation in most (all?) cases, and one has to keep in mind that French people tend to be more direct than some other people.

Comment: thank you! would you say it carries any sort of rude or condescending undertones at all ? for instance if it could be construed as a bit of an overreaction in the context of a small setback for example (i’m only partially familiar with french culture and don’t want to make assumptions)

Comment: _A good translation in most (all?) cases_. Well, it's not the topic but consider the impersonal forms like _Il va falloir se remuer le derrière_. Echoing that should prove difficult because I can't imagine _one will have to move their ass_ being idiomatic (but I'm no native speaker here). The impersonal turn creates less proximity than  _one_ does and it's not exactly _we_ either. My point is that even though _move your ass_ works well when you tell that to someone, it may not be what you'll use to translate those impersonal turn of phrases where it appears so it's a caveat there imho.

Comment: I must point out to non-anglophone readers that "ass" is strictly American English. British, Australian, New Zealand and perhaps other forms of English use the word "arse".